# Camelot is merging whole data on a page, I only want the first table data

Tags: extract, tabula, python-camelot

I am using Camelot to extract tabular data from a pdf file. The pdf on the last page contains two tables and some text in between. Camelot is interpreting it as one table even when I specified the table to tables[0]. Is there a way extract only the first table and nothing else.

I tried using this code

```
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_path, flavor='stream',pages=getPage(pdf_path))
    
    Array = []
    table_content = dict()
    
    table = tables[0]
    # Extract the table data as a list of lists
    record = table.df.values.tolist()
    
    table_data = dict(record)
    # Append the table data to the table_content list

    for key in table_data:
            table_content = table_content | {"question":key,"answer":table_data[key]}
            Array.append(table_content)
        
    json_dict = dict() | {"screening_questions":Array}
    
    return json_dict
```

Comment: You can try to use `flavor='lattice'`. See https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/how-it-works.html